# Вопрос по отрисовке компонента в React используя Roter

Tags: reactjs, маршрутизация, react-router-dom

есть вот такой вот код:
https://github.com/bardankl/test/blob/master/src/modules/Post.js
Один из вопросов - в компонент приходит id из (match.params) я его загоняю в state а дальше хочу использовать его, дабы вытянуть нужную мне информацию подходящую для этого ID. И вот в чем загвоздка, id в state меняется, а компонент не тянется. То есть не срабатывает моя ф-ция getPost. А почему ? Что я не так сделал ? Что-то с жизненными циклами ?

Ну и второй вопрос по поводу концепции как таковой. 
Есть родительский компонент, который будет рендерить список статей, при нажатии на определенную статью в списке, я хочу передавать id статью в дочерний компонент, и уже он будет лезть в базу и тянуть нужную статью по ID и он же будет её рендерить. Правильно ли я выстроил цепочку действий, или нужно как иначе ,есть какие-либо бест практисы ?

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере `getPost` срабатывает при пустом state.id, поскольку поступивший id, вы присваиваете уже после него. Надо в `componentDidMount` написать так:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({id: this.props.match.params.id}, {
        this.getPost();
    })
};
```

или в конструкторе написать:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        endPoint:'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/',
        post: '',
        id: props.match.params.id
    };
}
```

в общем инициализировать id до getPost

`getDerivedStateFromProps` в вашем случае лишний и его можно вообще убрать

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.  Заметил, что эта строка в коде у меня вообще лишняя  this.setState({id: this.props.match.params.id}) Так как я получаю, меняю id из props в методе getDerivedStateFromProps.   Но вот нужная статья все равно не тянется :( getPost не срабатывает :( Видимо я его где-то не там вызываю... что делать то ?

Comment: Все, нашел причину:) componentDidUpdate(prevProps) в этом методе жизненного цикла нужно было вызывать мой метод обращения в "базу". Он сравнивает предыдущий и текущий props.

Answer (score 0):

Все, нашел причину:) componentDidUpdate(prevProps){} в этом методе жизненного цикла нужно было вызывать мой метод обращения в "базу". Он сравнивает предыдущий и текущий props.